# Reason behind the Tour Down Under "People's Choice Classic"

Tags: racing

The [Tour Down Under (TDU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_Down_Under) is technically a 6-stage race, but the day before is the "People's Choice Classic",

> The People's Choice Classic, also known as the Down Under Classic, is a single day road cycling race held in Adelaide, South Australia, Australia. The race is the official warm-up for the Tour Down Under. Founded in 2006, the race exists as a men's only competition

The race is the day before Stage 1, but it doesn't have any bearing on the Tour Down Under, and riders [don't earn UCI points](http://www.tourdownunder.com.au/frequently-asked-questions.htm#970).

Is there any specific reason this is not part of the TDU?

My first thought was it's good for attendance/marketing/etc for "the race" to both start and finish on a weekend (and both take place very near the city-centre), but there might be some UCI rule preventing a 7-stage.. but this theory is completely unfounded (I couldn't find anything to this effect in the UCI rules/race-guidelines)

Comment: I would imagine the People's Choice is organized by a different promoter. It's not uncommon for promoters of local races to schedule their event just before or after a bigger race to take advantage of the fact that a bunch of pro teams are in town. They may have even worked out an agreement with the TDU to not have them overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[It's complicated](http://inrng.com/2014/01/uci-world-tour/)**, and this may not be all there is to it.

From my reading of [part 2 of the UCI WorldTour regulations (p43-44)](http://www.uciworldtour.com/Modules/BUILTIN/getObject.asp?MenuId=MTcxNw&ObjTypeCode=FILE&type=FILE&id=34028&LangId=1) is

- The duration of new "Continental" events is 5 days, unless the event has an exemption from the committee. Existing events have the same duration they had in 2004. The [Tour Down Under](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Tour_Down_Under) went for 6 days in 2004.
- A prologue can be included if

  - It does not exceed 8km.
  - It is time trial.
  - It counts as a race day.

This all confirms your suspicion that it's due to the rules. The Peoples Classic was 50km, and was not a time trial, so it couldn't be part of the TDU. As you say, it was good for attendance and marketing (and publicity).

Comment: Ahh, interesting.. Matching the distance in 2004 seems to explain it (and also why I came across many races of varying durations in finding similar races) - thanks!